# @mixin and @include won't handle more than 1 variable

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I'm using 7-1 architecture and am trying to use @mixin / @includes within _typography.scss file.

I will demonstrate what works over the visual studio live server function first and that is as follows:

```
@mixin font-prop($h1-size) {
    font-size: $h1-size;
}

$h1-size-desktop: 3.83rem;
$h1-size-tablet: 3.00rem;
$h1-size-mobile: 2.5rem;

$h2-size-desktop: 2.83rem;
$h2-size-tablet: 2.00rem;
$h2-size-mobile: 2.00rem;

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    h1 {
        @include font-prop($h1-size-mobile);
    }
    h2 {
        @include font-prop($h2-size-mobile);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 601px){
    h1 {
        @include font-prop($h1-size-tablet);
    }
    h2 {
        @include font-prop($h2-size-tablet);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1101px) {
    h1 {
        @include font-prop($h1-size-desktop);
    }
    h2 {
        @include font-prop($h2-size-desktop);
    }
}
```

However, if I try to add a second variable ($h1-weight) within @mixin "font-prop" like the below, nothing updates. Not even the $h1-size (first variable). Even if I add background-color into h1/h2 it's simply not entering there nor updating. It's like it all locks up?

```
@mixin font-prop($h1-size, $h1-weight) {
    font-size: $h1-size;
    font-weight: $h1-weight;
}

$h1-weight-mobile: 300;

$h1-size-desktop: 3.83rem;
$h1-size-tablet: 3.00rem;
$h1-size-mobile: 2.5rem;

$h2-size-desktop: 2.83rem;
$h2-size-tablet: 2.00rem;
$h2-size-mobile: 2.00rem;

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    h1 {
        @include font-prop($h1-size-mobile, $h1-weight-mobile);
    }
    h2 {
        @include font-prop($h2-size-mobile);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 601px){
    h1 {
        @include font-prop($h1-size-tablet);
    }
    h2 {
        @include font-prop($h2-size-tablet);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1101px) {
    h1 {
        @include font-prop($h1-size-desktop);
    }
    h2 {
        @include font-prop($h2-size-desktop);
    }
}
```

Even if I attempt to write the value directly within the @include on the second position, it still does not work.

```
@mixin font-prop($h1-size, $h1-weight) {
    font-size: $h1-size;
    font-weight: $h1-weight;
}

$h1-weight-mobile: 300;

$h1-size-desktop: 3.83rem;
$h1-size-tablet: 3.00rem;
$h1-size-mobile: 2.5rem;

$h2-size-desktop: 2.83rem;
$h2-size-tablet: 2.00rem;
$h2-size-mobile: 2.00rem;

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    h1 {
        @include font-prop($h1-size-mobile, 300);
    }
    h2 {
        @include font-prop($h2-size-mobile);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 601px){
    h1 {
        @include font-prop($h1-size-tablet);
    }
    h2 {
        @include font-prop($h2-size-tablet);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1101px) {
    h1 {
        @include font-prop($h1-size-desktop);
    }
    h2 {
        @include font-prop($h2-size-desktop);
    }
}
```

I have tested extensively and for some reason 2 or more variables causes isues and it won't update anything from this style sheet. As soon as I roll back to the first code block above that has just 1 variable of $h1-size, it works!

Update: I realise I'm getting this in the output but not sure what it means?

I'm getting this in the output:

"Compilation Error
Error: Missing argument $h1-weight.
╷
3   │ @mixin font-prop($h1-size, $h1-weight) {
│        ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ declaration
... │
23  │         @include font-prop($h2-size-mobile);
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ invocation"

Answer (score 0):

I realise It won't compile if I miss the second argument which is $h1-weight from all @include font-prop! As soon as I add in the second argument in all the font-prop mixins it compiles and works!